# How to disable automatic table modification in jHipster?

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase, jhipster

I'm trying connect my jhipster app with a custom mssql database. Right now it is connected to a fresh default MySQL db tied up with liquibase and has the default entites that come out-of-the-box with jhipster. I want to do 2 things :

1. Prevent any db modification scripts that liquibase may run on start up e.g. entity creation
2. Saftely move over to a different db with old applicaiton data and many custom tables than the one that is fresh and configured by default in jhipster .

To do '1' I tried to do the following in

```
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

 liquibase.setDropFirst(liquibaseProperties.isDropFirst());
        if (env.acceptsProfiles(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_NO_LIQUIBASE)) {
            liquibase.setShouldRun(false);
        } else {
            liquibaseProperties.setEnabled(false); // <<<<<< I DISABLED IT HERE
            liquibase.setShouldRun(liquibaseProperties.isEnabled());
            log.debug("Configuring Liquibase");
        }


}
```

But still I can see that liquibase scripts are being run in start-up. Please advice if I'm doing this correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #1, you could do it several ways, as you have both mssql and MySQL: you could either use the JDBC URL in DatabaseConfiguration or modify the Liquibase changelogs to add [conditions on dbms](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/preconditions.html) to exclude them for mssql

For #2, you should look for existing tools to convert from one database engine to another.

Comment: Thanks for #1, it's just what I wanted. I've also updated my question #2 to make it more clear, from your answer #2 I felt my question was misleading previously. Do you have a different answer for it?

Comment: Not sure I understand it but maybe you could run Liquibase on old db and generate changelogs from it that you could then insert into your jhipster master.xml